# Meaning of "vous condition" on baptism records from Maine and Canada in Drouin Collection?

Tags: canada, baptism-records, translation, maine

In the Parish records (Drouin Collection) in Maine and Canada I have found several baptism records that state "vous condition".  I do not speak french and I am not sure of the first word as the handwriting isn't always easy either.  I wanted to know what that means.

Comment: Does it say "sous condition"? That would mean "on condition" and be indicative of a [conditional baptism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_baptism). I will write up an answer if you can confirm this is what the record states. It may also be helpful to include a fuller excerpt of the wording on the record.

Comment: @vervet I didn't see your comment before starting my answer.

Comment: @JanMurphy No worries, I can't imagine it would say anything else

Comment: Dana, Welcome to G&FH.SE!  If you want to add anything to your question, such as a snippet of the image showing the handwriting, you can use the edit link under the question.  More information can be found in the [help].  The [tour] is also available to show how the site works.

Answer (score 4):

The FamilySearch Research Wiki's [French Wordlist](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/French_Wordlist) has this entry:

> *baptisé sous condition* = conditionally baptized

Could this be the phrase you are seeing?

Conditional baptisms are performed where there is some question about whether the previous baptism was done in a proper fashion.

Wikipedia has a brief article on [conditional baptism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_baptism), which says (citing the Book of Common Prayer):

> In a typical baptism, the minister of the sacrament (in the Catholic
>   Church usually a deacon or a priest, but sometimes, especially when
>   the baptized is in imminent danger of death, a lay person) says
>
> ```
> I baptize you in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit.
> ```
>
> while pouring water upon the head of the one being baptized, or
>   immersing him or her in water. In a conditional baptism, the minister
>   of the sacrament says
>
> ```
> If you are not yet baptized, I baptize you in the name of the Father
>   and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit.
> ```

Could the phrase be *baptisé sous condition*?